# Spring Boot request body validation add customize messages when input an invalid data type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

I am using Spring Boot to create a POST request and I need to validate the request body based on user inputs. However, when the user inputS an invalid data type, the response shows nothing, just `400 bad request` status. Can I add a message to show the user which field is an invalid data type?

For example:
Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/foo")
public class FooController {

  @PostMapping("/save")
  public void postFoo(@Valid @RequestBody Foo foo) {
    // do somethings
  }
}
```

And here is my Foo class:

```
public class Foo {
  @NotBlank
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  // getter/setter
}
```

So now I post a request as below:

```
{
  "name": "Foo Name",
  "age": "A String"
}
```

The server will respond with the status `400 Bad request` without any message. How can I put my message such as `Age must be an integer`.

Until now I only have a solution that changes Age to String and adds a @Pattern validation annotation.

```
public class Foo {
  @NotBlank
  private String name;
  @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]*", message = "Age must be an intege")
  private String age;

  // getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact body in the HTTP 400 response. I usually do see particular fields.

Comment: You cannot as that isn't validation but an error from Jackson trying to place a `String` into an `Integer` field. So it doesn't even reach validation it already fails at converting that JSON into an object.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, you're correct and I know it's a bad idea. Could you have any advice to add an error message for the Age field when posting a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everybody. I found a way to add messages and respond to users can aware of the error by using `ControllerAdvice` and overriding the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` method as example below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandlerConfig extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
 @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
                                                              HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    if (ex.getCause() instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
        InvalidFormatException iex = (InvalidFormatException) ex.getCause();
        List<Map<String, String>> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        iex.getPath().forEach(reference -> {
            Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
            error.put(reference.getFieldName(), iex.getOriginalMessage());
            errors.add(error);
        });

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errors, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus(), request);
    }
    return super.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(ex, headers, status, request);
}
}
```

The response will be:

```
[
    {
        "testId": "Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String \"accm\": not a valid Long value"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your post method signature, you can make use of Response Entity class to show some exception message that is to be returned to the user, along with some status code.

`public class FooController{`

`public ResponseEntity<?> showError()`

`{`

`return new ResponseEntity<>("Exception arised", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`

`}`

`}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement error handling mechanism.

In your error handler you need to catch all exceptions and return error response.
Here is an example based on  Controller level ExceptionHandling

```
public class FooController{

   //...
   @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
   @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class })
      public ErrorResponse handleException() {
      //
   }
}
```

Here in ErrorResponse  model you can set error code and message according to exception and via ResponseStatus you can assign http errro code

However this his approach has a major drawback: The @ExceptionHandler annotated method is only active for that particular Controller, not globally for the entire application.

To globally handle exception you can use ControllerAdvice.
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) is a good article on overall error handling mechanism

Comment: I have `ControllerAdvice` also, but you know when you give an invalid data type spring will response 400 bad request immediately before my code is excuted

Comment: What exception you are getting for invalid data type? You need to handle that exception in your controller advice